# Question on Lithiation Site in Directed Metalation

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have seen this from the [Baran group meeting material](https://www.scripps.edu/baran/images/grpmtgpdf/Krawczuk_March_08.pdf)
Here, why does lithiation not happen at C2 position? Why does tBuLi specifically litigate the C4 position only?

[image]

Comment: Do not underestimate the steric bulk of the TIPS group. Have you read the referenced articles? They may comment on this. They may also indicate whether any C2 lithiation was observed.